# Using Merge Tool in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, merge

I have two polygon layers which represent the same thing and I want to merge them to keep all the features in A and "fill in the gaps" with B.

Should I be using the merge tool here?

I'm using ArcMap 10.5.

Comment: Union will preserve your attribution http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/tools/analysis-toolbox/union.htm

Comment: A screenshot would help

Answer (score 1):

If there are no overlaps between the two feature classes, then you can use merge. However, there could be some cases where features of A are covered by B. Then the easiest way is to use the "Update" tool (updating B with A) but it is only available with an advanced licence. Alternatively, this can be done with the "union" tool and then you will need to clean the attribute table.